# Highcharts Pie Chart Drilldown not showing on third drill

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two issues:

1. The third drilldown the names of the DataLabels appear as "Slice" instead of their respective names. Is this a bug or do I need to specify it somewhere?
2. When I apply a color theme, every drilldown the colors reset and just randomly generate other colors. (I have 20 colors in the series for the theme file)
3. Is there also a way to drill back up? IE have an external button or control that allows user to go back up a level? For me I dont know if it is intuitive to go back to the original and drilldown again.

Here is my JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lzhm6/

I have everything working great except these issues and hopefully can help others trying to do the same thing.

*Also note I am using the new source code: https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/js/highcharts.src.js which fixes the label errors.

*I am getting an error everytime I drilldown:

```
point.select is not a function
[Break On This Error] point.select(null, event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.shiftKey);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played with the first A data section, and changed it to this:

```
            data: [{
                y: 33.06,
                name: 'A',
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Budweiser',
                    data: [
                        {name:'A', y:10838}
                        , {name:'B', y:11349}
                        , {name:'C', y:11894}
                        , {name:'D', y:11846}
                        , {name:'E', y:11878}
                        , {name:'F', y:11662}
                        , {name:'G', y:11652}
                    ],
                    color: colors[0]
                }},
```

This is working perfectly for me. I pulled the categories and data nodes into a single array of name/data object nodes in the data array. Check the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzhm6/16/) to see how the changes worked.

1. Click A-1
2. Click A

Comment: thanks dan, i figured it out this morning after a wonderful dream. I have the solution on highcharts forum as well! now if i could figure out the drilling up solution

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shadmehr/uRTh5/3/) or use the following code in the drilldown part:

```
data: [
    ['slice_name',10],
    ['slice_name',7],
    ['slice_name',33],
    ['slice_name',2]
]
```