# d.select is not a function

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use the drilldown pie chart (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzhm6/16/)).
I found this at following posts answer:
[Highcharts Pie Chart Drilldown not showing on third drill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422616/highcharts-pie-chart-drilldown-not-showing-on-third-drill)

This fulfills my need perfectly, but I get an error when I click on pie slice to drilldown to next level. The error is:
`d.select is not a function` i.e. at `d.select(null,a.ctrlKey||a.metaKey||a.shiftKey)`

Could you please help me out????

Thanks 
JC

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. By default click event selects point (click any point here: http://highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic).

In your point click handler you destroy clicked point (by setting new data with setData method) but you don't cancel default action, so Highcharts is trying to select not existing point and this causes error.

As I wrote before, solution is quite simple, you can just return false in

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      var drilldown = this.drilldown;

      if (drilldown) { // drill down
        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
      } else { // restore
        setChart(name, categories, data);
      }

      // return false to prevent default action
      return false;
    }
  }
},
```

Here you can find a working demo: http://jsbin.com/ocegap/1